# Visual studio code concept is not working

Tags: json, visual-studio, visual-c++, terminal, compiler-errors

I am learining C++. and working on visual studio code. but whenever i tried to work with #include<concepts> it give me error. like when i am creating a template concept xyz = requires(T t){} it gives me two error. concept, xyz does not name a type. my gcc  g++ is updated. how can i solve this issue

i also change my code runner setting to run code on terminal.